# cmpb using GDB, need help understanding the expected response

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have an assignment to use GDB to figure out passwords of a program provided to me.  I am doing alright with following the assembly dump of the program (so far) but am stuck on understanding `cmpb` instruction set.  I've recorded the value in the respective registers, but am lost as to what is happening with the values in the registers when `cmpb` is called.  I've read other threads, like [understand cmpb and loops in assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801152/understand-cmpb-and-loops-in-assembly-language) but still goes over my head.

Here is a snippet of my terminal session:

```
   0x0804844a <+6>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0804844f <+11>:    cmpb   $0x0,(%edx)  // $edx has "something\n"
   0x08048452 <+14>:    je     0x804845d <s+25>  // skipped since it's not equal to $0x0
   0x08048454 <+16>:    add    $0x1,%eax // adding "something\n" to $0x1
=> 0x08048457 <+19>:    cmpb   $0x0,(%edx,%eax,1)  //what is the result here???
   0x0804845b <+23>:    jne    0x8048454 <s+16>
```

Now in the link I mentioned above, it states that

> "takes a byte that EDX+EAX points to and compares it to zero. EDX
>   serves as the string base pointer, EAX is the index. Scale is 1
>   because we're working with bytes. Think of the whole loop this way:
>   for(eax=0; edx[eax] != 0; eax++)."

But what byte exactly?

I mean, if `$edx` == "something\n" and `$eax` == `0x1` (I know this because when I call for the contents of `$eax` it states that `<Address 0x1 out of bounds>`, then what byte is compared and/or what would be the result?

Comment: `(%edx,%eax,1)` this is `%edx+%eax+1`. eax register is like a dynamic offset to `edx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first cmp instruction:

```
cmpb   $0x0,(%edx)
```

tests if string is empty. If empty, doesn't enter in the loop.

The next cmp instruction

```
cmpb   $0x0,(%edx,%eax,1)
```

checks if 0 is in address made of the sum of edx & eax registers + 1. `eax` doesn't contain any address, but acts like an *offset*. The base address is `%edx`

in the end `%eax` contains the string length.

Comment: so in my case, if the file expects the password, and the password matches what is expected, the sum should be '0'?  Or am I confusing sum with the `&&` operation?

Comment: you've shown us the disassembly of the string length, not the string compare. Before comparing data, it seems to compute length.

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand your explanation.